# Spark cassandra connector - access the RDD in where condidtion

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

Let's assume I have an `RDD[Foo]` where `case class Foo(bar: String, baz: Int)` and I have a table in Cassandra, with a partitioning key `bar` and clustering key `baz`

Now, I'm trying to join the RDD with that table and do some filtering on the clustering key:

```
rdd.joinWithCassandraTable("my_keyspace", "foo_table").where("baz < ???")
```

What should I put in place of `???` to access the `baz` property of the `RDD`?

I'd like to achieve the same result as in the following pseudo-sql:

```
select * from my_keyspace.foo_table ct
join rdd
on ct.bar = rdd.bar
where ct.baz < rdd.baz
```

Comment: @RameshMaharjan the question you've linked is about the partitioning key. This one is about dynamic filter values on clustering key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`where` is used for static predicates embedded in the Cassandra query. It cannot be used for filtering based on `RDD`.

For that you'll have to use standard `filter` (and consequently move selection to the Spark side).

Comment: can you add any example to make your answer better?

Comment: using filter() is easy, though it seems like a potential performance impact - I'd be reading the entire partition. Would my scenario be achievable using e.g. Spark SQL instead of the cassandra connector?